# Flash Audio Player - M3U

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, audio-player, m3u

I'm trying to read some .m3u files with my society flash audio player but it doesn't work. I need it to read radio flux (.m3u) and the only type of files working is .mp3.

I read somewhere that I have to parse the file and recover the MP3 files. I really don't know how to do this. Do you have any idea to make it work?

Comment: .m3u files are somewhat free-form but it should be pretty straightforward to parse out the stuff you need (likely to be URLs to .mp3 files). Can you update your question with a small sample of .m3u data that you'll be working with?

Comment: Hi :). I'm working with something like "http://streaming.radio.rtl.fr/rtl-1-44-96".. That's my problem ^^'.

Comment: Can I see an example .m3u playlist? That link is an MP3 stream.

Comment: I know, but my boss gave me just this... I have to work with this type of link.